Menhir Parser Functor?
Is it possible to make Menhir generate a functor? Or something to that effect?
For a small example, say you have a family of languages that share the same structure except for the value type and keywords. Say I have a module signature:
module type M = sig
  type value_type
  type keyword
end

with some AST functor:
module AST (M : M) = struct
  type t = ...
  ...
end

I can define multiple AST variants with different types and keywords by instantiating them with different M. e.g. AST1 = AST(M1), AST2 = AST(M2), etc.
If I want a Parser for AST(M).t, however, I am limited to making a different parser for each AST1, AST2, etc, unless there's a way to make the parser parametric on M.
I can alternatively define an intersection AST that can then be converted into each variant. But this requires traversing every AST after parsing, so I was hoping Menhir perhaps can do it in a single step.

You can define a parameterized parser by adding a %parameter header to your parser:
%parameter<M:sig
  type value
  type keyword
end>

The menhir repository has an example at https://gitlab.inria.fr/fpottier/menhir/-/blob/master/demos/calc-param/parser.mly?ref_type=heads#L4.
With this parameter will generate the parsing code inside a Make functor that you can call with your various implementation.

oh, thank you very much! I didn't see this. I'll try it out. I would basically need to call something like Parser.Make(M), right?

Yes, you need to create the parser with module Parser_for_M=Parser.Make(M).

thank you for this!
to follow up, I had to separate the tokens into a token.mly file, compile that before, then call it from the lexer. the example conveniently has a dune file that teaches you how to set this up in dune.
Is there a way to use an existing Module Signature instead of hardcoding the Signature each time? i.e.
%parameter<M: SomeModule.SomeSignature>
instead of M: sig ... end

ah, nevermind. I figured this out. I have to use the correct module names as specified in the dune file... <M : DuneName.SomeModule.SomeSignature>
